# Raspberry Pi 1 Model A+ Error

Tags: raspberry-pi

I recently got myself a Raspberry Pi Model A+, a CanaKit 6 ft HDMI cable and some 8 GB SanDisk Micro SD cards. Then I installed RISC OS to one of the cards using Win32 Disk Imager.

My problem is when I plug one of my 5V phone chargers into my Pi, all I get is 8 flashes from the green ACT light with no output to the monitor. On top of this problem, this error isn't documented at all.

Will I have to get a new Pi or will I just have to install a different OS to the SD card?

Answer (score 1):

The [Embedded Linux Wiki](http://elinux.org/R-Pi_Troubleshooting#Green_LED_blinks_in_a_specific_pattern) has troubleshooting info:

> 8 flashes: SDRAM not recognised. You need newer bootcode.bin/start.elf firmware.

Also see https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/44675/raspberry-pi-2-model-b-green-led-is-blinking-8-times for more.